# Forcing packets through a TUN interface on Mac?

Tags: vpn, iproute, tunneling

I am wanting to build a toy VPN server/client. This isn't impossible to setup on Linux due to the beautiful `iproute2` package and granular routing control. However, on Mac the experience has been terrible.

I have a `TUN` interface I created on my machine, but how can I simply intercept all packets by rerouting them to the TUN device, listen for the packets, then forward them off to the router/default gateway?

Before implementing the VPN client, I simply wanted to prove that I could intercept the packets, print out their data then have them forward off as they initially intended to. I cannot get this to work.